# Upgrading Bootstrap SASS in Visual Studio hosted Angular app

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, sass

I have an application that is using an ASP.NET MVC project and controllers that is an envelope to an Angular-based SPA hosted inside of that project.  Previous developers implemented SASS port of Bootstrap 3.3.0 and I need to get it up to 3.3.7. Most documentation on the Official Port of Bootstrap 2/3 is catering to ruby/npm implementations.  How does one keep up on updates effectively in a Visual Studio world or should I simply update it externally using rake, ruby, npm, etc? Any guides or assistance is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After more research it looks like rake and the instructions found on the twbs readme may be sufficient from a command line standpoint but if anyone has further thoughts feel free to add.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#upstream-converter

Also have found a Nuget package that may provide better support than the handrolled version in place in the project now. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap.Sass/